# Rock, paper and scissors improvement: Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python and have attempted to write a little project relating to the subject above.

```
import random


option = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];   
pc_selection = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];  
pc_move = random.choice(pc_selection)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def first_condition():
    select = raw_input("Please select your choice\n") 
    print "Your choice:", select
    if select in option:
        pc_move
        print "Computer choice:", pc_move
    else:
        first_condition() 

    if select == pc_move:
        print "Result: draw"
    elif select == "rock" and pc_move == "paper":
        print "Result: Computer wins"
    elif select == "paper" and pc_move == "scissors":
        print "Result: Computer wins"
    elif select == "scissors" and pc_move == "rock":
        print "Result: Computer wins"

    elif select == "rock" and pc_move == "scissors":
        print "Result: You win"
    elif select == "paper" and pc_move == "rock":
        print "Result: You win"
    elif select == "scissors" and pc_move == "paper":
        print "Result: You win"


first_condition()
```

I know my code aren't very efficient (fastest and cleverest), so my question is:

Which part could I amend to make my project as shortest as possible without losing its functionaility, i.e. using other functions that could reduce the length of my code?

Thanks!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficient as possible'? Ease of modification? Ease of understanding? Smallest space (memory)? Smallest time? etc. These are mutually conflicting requirements? ;-/ i.e. 'Rule 3: Good, Fast, Cheap - Pick Two'

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What I am looking for is a code that is fast and good aiming to eliminate whats unnecessary as possible. What I don't feel right at the moment is having too many elif within my code.

Answer (score 1):

Every option in the option list is beaten by the option that precedes it. If the choices are different then it can be assumed that user wins if the computer did not choose the item that precedes the user's choice in the list. Example:

```
import random

option = ["scissors", "paper", "rock"] # I reversed the original list
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def first_condition():
    pc_move = random.choice(option) # there only needs to be 1 option list
    select = raw_input("Please select your choice\n") 
    print "Your choice:", select
    if select in option:
        print "Computer choice:", pc_move
    else:
        return first_condition() 
    if pc_move == select:
        print("Draw")
        return
    # find the index of the user's choice
    index = option.index(select) 
    # did the pc choose the item before this one?       
    you_win = option[index-1] != pc_move

    print("You %s" % ("win" if you_win else "lose"))

while True:
    print("-"*50)
    first_condition()
```

Comment: Hi user2682863. Thank you for your explanation, the above code is concise and has the same functionality! However could you explain the reason for the last part where you have the "while True" part? Whats the intention of having it?

Comment: I just added that to test it. I ran it through several iterations to make sure it worked as expected. - if it solves your problem please feel free to accept it as the answer